# Exclude posts with specific tag

Tags: wordpress, posts

I want to exclude (hide) post have specific tag.

I use this code

```
function post_to_exclude ($query){
    global $wp_query;
    if ( ( $query->is_home() || $query->is_feed() ||  $query->is_search() || $query->is_archive() || $query->is_single()) )  {
        $query->set('tag__not_in', array(15) );
    }

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'post_to_exclude');
```

But doesn’t work when page `is_sigle()`, I still can access the page permalink

Any ideas how I might accomplish this?